# Android : Button Writes on an external file

Tags: android, file-io

I want my android application to read and write from external files.

I have a button that I want in its action to create (or read from already created file) and read and write from this file

I am using this code

```
try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\DHA\\OnlineConsultationFile\\out.txt\\");
        fstream.write("Some String");
        fstream.flush();
        fstream.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it doesn't write anything on the file.

And then I need to read the content of this file

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorial [Reading and Writing a file to SD card sample program in Android](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523) from java-samples.com.

Overview from the tutorial:

> This sample android program shows you how write and read a file from SD Card in Android. In this program four buttons are shown and a Edit box. When you type some text into the edit box and click, Save to SD Card button, the text is saved to a text file and saved to the SD Card. When you click clear button, the edit box contents are cleared. When you click, Read Sd card button the file is read from the SD card and the contents are copied to the edit box.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your maniferst file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
..... 
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(root, "out.txt");
if (root.canWrite()) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourFile)); 
    bw.write("SOME CONTENT");
    bw.close();
}    
......
```

Make sure you have permissions to write to external storage.

Comment: can u help me with the permission line ?